# Auto Scroll of theTableView

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have got a requirement in which i have to autoScroll my tableView.. that is, the rows are getting added dynamically and I have to enable the autoScroll feature as the rows are getting added..

Help me out. Thanks in advance.

**LOGCAT :**

```
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:231) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:213) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:204) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at com.example.animation_linear.Animation$LongOperation$1.run(Animation.java:89) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 11:26:39.474: E/AndroidRuntime(373): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
```

I think the problem is that am initiating it inside asyncTask like this as my requirement is to animate image after image

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {             
                    int a =0;
                    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

                        tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                        for (int col = 0; col < layout; col++) {

                            image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                            iv[a]   =   image;
                            image.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                            android.view.animation.Animation animation =    animate(a);
                            image.setAnimation(animation);
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);

                            tableRow.addView(image);

                            a++;

                            VSC.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   VSC.fullScroll(tableLayout.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                }

                            });
                        }
                        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                    }
                    //VSC.addView(tableLayout);
                    HSC.addView(VSC);
                    setContentView(HSC);





                }
            });

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

See the link [java.lang.IllegalStateException when adding a View in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170181/java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-adding-a-view-in-debug-mode). How to debug the issue? Please help me

Comment: do you also want it to scroll automatically to the end of the table when a row is added?

Comment: Yeah... On the view only 6 rows can appear at a time in the emulator. When the 7th row is added the tableView has to autoScroll to down to automaticaaly show up the added row.

Comment: @Shruti: None of the answers helped yaar. :( I was not able to do that.

Answer (score 4):

In android tableView called as TableLayout [here](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/) is the tutorial, will show you how to add rows to TableLayout dynamically.
For scrolling feature you can always use ScrollView mentioned in older answers.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the rows are getting added dynamically and even the ScrollViews are added. Its not the problem. But my requirement is when a new row adds up the ScrollBar should auto scroll in order to show up the newly added row. How can I do this? Can you help me!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087877/scroll-to-last-line-of-tablelayout-within-a-scrollview

Answer (score 1):

try like this in your xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:scrollbars="vertical" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tLayout"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >   
</TableLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

In your .java class, use id of `TableLayout` to add rows dynamically, When number of rows will exceed the screen height, scrollbar will be shown.

OR

Simply add :

**android:isScrollContainer="true"**

as shown below in your TableLayout

```
<TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tLayout"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            >   
    </TableLayout>
```

**EDIT**

As told by you

> *the rows are getting added dynamically*

for that you can use

```
TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tLayout);    
TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
//to add row on table ,you can use loops to add multiple rows on table
tl.addView(tr1);
```

refer this [urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183968/how-to-add-rows-dynamically-into-table-layout)

And to remove exception try this

```
if(tl !=null)
tl.removeAllViews();
```

if you don't want to remove all views and add new views everytime

you can add row using index like this

```
tl.addView(child, index); //where child is row
```

see this answer [Android TableRow - How to add View dynamically to certain postion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345189/android-tablerow-how-to-add-view-dynamically-to-certain-postion)

Comment: When i refer my table layout by the ID, the program is crashing.

Comment: is your tablelayout not empty ?

Comment: I have added a tableRow in it.

Comment: I have added the rows in the same way. Somewhere I am missing out something. So am getting the exceptiopn. I am trying to debug. Will let you know if it works out :)

Comment: You are adding some views on row that are added on a row before ,that why you are getting this exception.. got thru these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132867/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-pare ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729573/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-m,  try giving an Unique ID for the table rows or the views you are adding to the table

Answer (score 1):

Put the Table Layout inside the ScrollView layout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/score_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/header"/>                    
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not creating tableView from Xml. Am creating it through the code itself. So can you tell me how to enable auto scrolling for the dynamically added TableView?

Comment: Create scroll view dynamically and start adding child view Table Layout to the ScrollView dynamically

Comment: @Shruti: Yeah I am trying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To scroll automatically to the end (assuming your TableView is contained by a ScrollView):

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

Edit: make sure your scrollview only has one child.

Let's say you have this layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And you want to use a scrollView. It should NOT look like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settingsContactInformationScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Instead, you should group everything you want to include in the scrollView into one layout and use that as a child of the scrollView, like so:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="Column 1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:text="Column 2" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: On using the code which you had posted i got the exception10-05 11:44:51.674: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
My code was-  VSC.fullScroll(tableLayout.FOCUS_DOWN); where VSC is the ScrollView and tableLayout is my Table.. Can you help me?How to debug it??

Comment: The ScrollView can only have one child. Check my updated answer please.